# Correctly Centering Button in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have seen this question asked and answered numerous times, but none of the answers seem to address the problem that it seems to be the top-left corner being centered, not the center of the button. This quickly becomes apparent as you increase the size of the button. Here is an example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="button">Hello</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
 }

.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 5rem; /* Just to make the issue apparent. */
}
```

See for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/7Laf8/3024/

My question: how do you position the button so that its center is at the center of the screen/div?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: try `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);` to the `.button` styles to center it perfectly.

Alternatively, there are [flexbox- and grid-based solutions](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/).

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/7Laf8/3035/ this solution might be what youre looking for

```
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

I added the `display: flex`, `justify-content: center`, and `align-items: center` to the `wrapper` class